# Getting returned value from a stored procedure in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, ado.net, plpgsql

I have a stored procedure in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dosmth()
RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

RETURN FALSE;

 END;
 $BODY$
 LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
```

From ado.net I need to retrieve the return value. I try to do the following:

```
   DbCommand cmd = DBTemplate.CreateStoredProcedureCommand(dbConnection, "dosmth");

   cmd.Parameters.Add(DBTemplate.CreateParameter(System.Data.DbType.Boolean,
                "@RETURN_VALUE", System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue));

   DBTemplate.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
   Boolean bl = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value);
```

Unfortunately this does not work telling me that the type `DBNull` cannot be converted to `Boolean`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`. I seem to recall that `ExecuteNonQuery` doesn't `return` a result either.